# Receiving broadcast UDP on a specific interface with Twisted Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, twisted, twisted.internet

I am working on an Ubuntu 14.04 server with multiple interfaces on different subnets.  I am trying to write a twisted(13.2.0) application that listens for broadcasts on one interface only, ignoring the other interfaces.

I am able to receive broadcasts with this code.

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import DatagramProtocol
from twisted.internet import reactor
import IN, socket, struct


class BroadcastListener(DatagramProtocol):

    def startProtocol(self):
        self.transport.getHandle().setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET,
                                       socket.SO_BROADCAST, True)

    def datagramReceived(self, datagram, address):
        print "Received datagram from %s" % (address[0])

#reactor.listenUDP(65001, BroadcastListener(), interface='192.168.1.1')
reactor.listenUDP(3200, BroadcastListener())

reactor.run()
```

I am sending test UDP broadcasts from another machine on the 192.168.1.x subnet with socat.

```
echo Hi |socat -  UDP-DATAGRAM:192.168.1.255:3200,broadcast
```

However, this will receive broadcasts on any interface on the server.  I thought it would be specificying the interface in reactor.listenUDP(), as I did the commented call.

If I use the reactor.listenUDP() call that includes the interface, I no longer receive broadcast.  I still receive unicasted UDP sent with socat.

```
echo Hi |socat -  UDP-DATAGRAM:192.168.1.1:3200
```

I can see when specifying the interface that the socket is bound to the interface.

```
$ netstat -an |grep udp |grep 3200
udp        0      0 10.10.0.1:3200          0.0.0.0:*
```

But the broadcasts are being dropped.  I confirmed with tcpdump the broadcasts are arriving to the server.

What is the correct way to set a UDP listener's interface in twisted python?

Comment: Have you tried `self.transport.getHandle().bind('192.168.1.1')`?

Comment: I have, well, `self.transport.getHandle().bind(('192.168.1.1', 3200))`, above and below the setsockopt() line.  Should I be putting it somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're on Linux here.  It seems that `bind()` won't work because it drops packets not addressed to the interface, which for broadcast packets is all of them.  Instead, try the socket option `SO_BINDTODEVICE`, which may not be in your Python `socket` module, but has the value `25` on my Linux system and probably on yours (check `/usr/include/asm-generic/socket.h`).  It takes an interface name rather than an IP address, so it should look something like this:

```
self.transport.getHandle().setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, 25, "eth0")
```

Comment: This seems like a potentially useful addition to Twisted if this is in fact the only way to do it.  I confess I don't actually know how to do this myself :).

Comment: I see now that it is linux.  I was aware the binding to the device would work, but read that option is linux only.  I was also considering using IP_PKTINFO to get the address the datagram was sent to, but I think that isn't multi-platform supported either.  I may end up retrieving the interface configurations and comparing the sender against the netmask.